# get .o file timestamp in linux .a library using c/c++

Tags: linux, timestamp, static-libraries

I have a LINUX static library (.a) that contains a bunch of object (.o) files.  In C/C++, does anybody know a way to get the .o file creation timestamp w/o extracting the files?  Thanks.

I suppose that I can just leave the .o file alone (in the directory) after adding it to .a.  Trying to better a neater solution.

Comment: Pretty sure ar keeps only one timestamp per file, which is mtime, not btime.